# How to enable scrollbar on overflow in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar

I don't want to show data from the database in tabular format so I have tried something like you have seen in the code. I have have added new `JPanel` containers consisting of button and label each time a record is retrieved from the database. But due to large amount of data, the panels are getting overflowed but no scroll option is getting enabled.

I have tried using `JScrollPane` many times but none of the ways helped me.

```
public class Test2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rt;
    public int PageId = 8236;

    /**
     * Creates new form Test2
     */
    public Test2() {
        initComponents();

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521","practice","perfect");
            st = con.createStatement();

            int height = 100;
            int width = sc.getWidth();
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select id, firstname || ' ' || lastname, salary from employee");
            while(rs.next()){
                JPanel g = new JPanel();
                g.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
                g.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                JLabel l = new JLabel(rs.getString(1));
                JLabel l1 = new JLabel(rs.getString(2));
                JLabel sal = new JLabel(rs.getString(3));
                JButton b = new JButton("View profile");
                b.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sc, "Clicked!!");
                    }
                });
                g.add(l);
                g.add(l1);
                g.add(b);
                sc.add(g);

                y += (height + 10);
            }
        }   
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Can't connect", "connection error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        sc = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        sc.setAutoscrolls(true);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout scLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(sc);
        sc.setLayout(scLayout);
        scLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            scLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 252, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        scLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            scLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 483, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(sc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(sc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel sc;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: If you don't wish to have a table, why not make it a `JList` instead? The 'details' button can be dropped in favor of a `ListSelectionListener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to show data from the database in tabular format

Why? Based on the code you provided the output will look terrible. You create multiple labels based on the text. That means the size of each label can be different which means the layout of each label over multiple rows will be random and unaligned.

If you want a button in a table column then check out: [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/).

> the panels are getting overflowed but no scroll option is getting enabled.

```
sc.setAutoscrolls(true);
```

That is not how you add scrolling to a component. The component needs to be added to a JScrollPane:

```
JPanel scrollingPanel = new JPanel();
scrollingPanel.setLayout(...);
scrollingPanel.add(...);
scrollingPanel.add(...);

getContentPane.add(new JScrollPane(scrollingPanel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
pack();
```

Note, I have never used the SpringLayout. I suggest you learn how to create your GUI's manually so you are not depending on the IDE to generated your code. It will be easier to understand and maintain the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Ok, I Will surely try how to use Table Button Column. :) :)

Comment: I have tried adding jScrollPane but after that, output is not even visible. Can you tell some other way in which I can solve my problem please.

Comment: Well, your code is still wrong. There is nothing complicated with using a JScrollPane. The problem is likely with the IDE generated code. Don't use the IDE to generate the code. Post an [mre] that demonstrates the problem. So forget about your application and start over. Create a Jframe with a JPanel that uses a vertical BoxLayout. Create a JScrollPane using this panel and add the scroll pane to the content pane of the frame. Then create a loop that adds multiple JLabels to the panel. Note how the scrollbar appears. Understand the basics first then figure out what is different with your code.